# How to avoid sonar error "use try-with-resources or close this ... in a "finally" clause" if custom close method is used (java 6)?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Here's the code:

```
Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = createConnection();
        String sql = String.format(STRING_FOR_PROCEDURE, name);
        connection.createStatement().execute(sql);
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DatabaseServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
```

I suppose sonar wants me to close connection in block "finally" with something like this:

```
connection.close();
```

But I use custom method for this which is:

```
    protected void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This method needs to be used in current class. But I receive sonar blocker "use try-with-resources or close this statement in a "finally" clause".
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar asks to "Use try-with-resources or close this "Connection" in a "finally" clause."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945517/sonar-asks-to-use-try-with-resources-or-close-this-connection-in-a-finally)

Comment: Can  you post your createConnection() method?

Comment: The easiest solution is to upgrade to a more recent Java version and use try-with-resources.

Comment: So I have to ask – why are you still using Java 6?

Comment: The huge project with tons of legacy is currently on 1.6, project was build in 2012 for the first time.

Comment: That is not a very good reason though: Java 7 was released in 2011.

Comment: I agree, but I am not the one who started the project. I participated this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your error is “use try-with-resources or close this **statement** in a "finally" clause.”

The problem isn’t how you close your Connection.  The problem is that you aren’t closing your Statement.

```
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
try {
    connection = createConnection();
    String sql = String.format(STRING_FOR_PROCEDURE, name);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute(sql);
    connection.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new DatabaseServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (statement != null) {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not close Statement.", e);
        }
    }
    closeConnection(connection);
}
```

Remember that the statement needs to be closed before the Connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar helps in designing proper code but sometimes if you are well aware we can ignore the warning.. but yes can you do this?

```
Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = createConnection();
        String sql = String.format(STRING_FOR_PROCEDURE, name);
        connection.createStatement().execute(sql);
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DatabaseServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```